# How can I change underline color for jshint in vscode for warnings from red to yellow?

Tags: jshint, visual-studio-code

I use vscode as a text-editor for frontend and backend development. For linting purposes I use jshint 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint'. The linter shows warnings with red colored underline, I would like to change that red color to yellow for warnings, is it possible, if yes then how to do it ?
Thank you all.